# Spring restTemplate.postForEntity(or postForObject) gives error "no suitable HttpMessageConverter" in Stand alone Java application

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, resttemplate

I have stand alone Java Application with Spring 3.0. I am calling REST service "post" method call with 4 integer parameters. While calling restTemplate.postForEntity(), I am getting error "no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type". Is it require to set any messageConverter in restTemplate ? i don't find any sample on net.

Comment: Can you post some code that helps to illustrate the problem?  With what you have currently given us, the best we can do is guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Funny, I just answered [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138346/consuming-key-value-pairs-using-spring-resttemplate/11138549#11138549)...*

Nevertheless you may want check great Spring Reference Manual, particularly [this fragment](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-resttemplate), [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.util.Map%29), [IBM Dev blog post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-restful/index.html) and [`RestTemplate` example on SpringSource Blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/) (written when ).

From SpringSource Blog post:

> **HttpMessageConverters**
>
> Objects passed to and returned from the methods
>   getForObject(), postForLocation(), and put() and are converted to HTTP
>   requests and from HTTP responses by HttpMessageConverters. Converters
>   for the main mime types and Java types are registered by default, but
>   you can also write your own converter and plug it in the RestTemplate.

Also, [IBM blog post here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-restful/index.html#N10148) mentions common HttpMessageConverter implementations, you probably will use Marshalling (response in XML) or MappingJackson (for JSON) one.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that REST service you called would have failed and postForObject() returned null. You need to check for errors using ResponseErrorHandler implementations.